# Firefox, bad svg image rendering

Tags: image, firefox, svg, render

I am experiencing bad rendering of SVG image with Firefox on Ubuntu. You can see on the attached image that the letter J has a little black line below it. This artifact happens only at certain zoom levels. The image is added with the `<img>` tag, so it is not a background. The image is created with Inkscape. It renders properly on Chrome, I didn't try on other OS.

Is there a way to fix this keeping SVG ?

[image: Svg image with bad rendering]

EDIT: since this affect only the image on the border, I found a workaround opening the SVG in a text editor and increasing the height and the width of a couple of pixels which means leaving a bit of transparent padding around the text.

I am still curious if this is a firefox bug though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Principle the rendering of SVG is not worse in Firefox than in any other browser. But each browser has its own little lacks in rendering, especially when shapes are close to each other and scaling comes into play.

So I might suggest to review your graphic and give a little room around the letter, so that there is no shape »snapping« directly to the outline of the letter. Unfortunately I cannot see the code of your graphic, but I am pretty sure that the issue is caused by shapes which are very close to each other (arranged by »snapping«) and there is no »saving overlap«.

For Fonts there is Hinting, what optimizes the rendering, especially for small sizes, but for SVG there is no such thing and since you cannot say for sure how each browser will handle those »edge cases« it is up to you to prepare the graphic so that those failures cannot appear.